# Separating Digits from a Phone Number

Tags: java

I have a problem from my AP Java class that I'm not able to figure out. Here it is:

> Pull Phone Number Apart
>
> Write a program that:  Prompts the user for
>   their phone number (no dashes), displays the phone number, the area
>   code, the middle three digits, and the last four digits.
>
> Remember, the greatest allowable value for an integer number is
>   2,147,483,647, so you cannot do a 262 number

And here's my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class PhoneNumber
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );

        System.out.println("Enter your phone number");
        int number = input.nextInt(); 

        int digit1 = number / 10000000000;  
        digit1 = digit1 % 1000000000;
        int digit2 = number / 10000000000;
        digit2 = digit2 % 1000000000;
        int digit3 = number / 10000000000;
        digit3 = digit3 % 1000000000;
        int digit4 = number / 1000000000;
        digit4 = digit4 % 1000000000;
        int digit5 = number / 10000000000;
        digit5 = digit5 % 1000000000;
        int digit6 = number / 1000000000;
        digit6 = digit6 % 100000000;
        int digit7 = number / 100000000;
        digit7 = digit7 % 10000000;
        int digit8 = number / 100000000;
        digit8 = digit8 % 10000000;
        int digit9 = number / 10000000;
        digit9 = digit9 % 1000000;
        int digit10 = number / 1000000;
        digit10 = digit10 % 100000;


        System.out.println("Phone number = " + number);
        System.out.println("Area code = " + digit1 + digit2 + digit3);
        System.out.println("Middle digits = " + digit4 + digit5 + digit6);
        System.out.println("Last four digits = " + digit7 + digit8 + digit9);       

    }

}
```

Here is the error I'm getting:
The literal 10000000000 of type int is out of range

Can anyone help me fix this? Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: "Remember, the greatest allowable value for an integer number is 2,147,483,647"

Comment: I would take a look at the BigInteger class or using the long datatype

Comment: Silly question: why don't you just add the individual "digits" into a string?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use the `long long` type, since it is a 64 bit-integer.
Well if is necessary to do that in java that simply use the `BigInteger` or as the other users say using `strings`.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
Integer.toString()
```

and operate from there on out. :)

In addition, PLEASE do not store phone numbers in integer fields in real life scenarios. Strings are much more suitable, since phone numbers can grow very long, and sometimes legally can contain non-numeric characters.

Answer (score 0):

Simply convert your phone number to String type. Use substring method to get your area code and other parts. Convert them back to Integer. You dont have to create so many int variables for this.

Answer (score 0):

you can make use long instead like this way

```
import java.util.Scanner; public class PhoneNumber {

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );

    System.out.println("Enter your phone number");
    int number = input.nextInt(); 

    long digit1 = number / 10000000000L;  
    digit1 = digit1 % 1000000000;
    long digit2 = number / 10000000000L;
    digit2 = digit2 % 1000000000;
    long digit3 = number / 10000000000L;
    digit3 = digit3 % 1000000000;
    int digit4 = number / 1000000000;
    digit4 = digit4 % 1000000000;
    long digit5 = number / 10000000000L;
    digit5 = digit5 % 1000000000;
    int digit6 = number / 1000000000;
    digit6 = digit6 % 100000000;
    int digit7 = number / 100000000;
    digit7 = digit7 % 10000000;
    int digit8 = number / 100000000;
    digit8 = digit8 % 10000000;
    int digit9 = number / 10000000;
    digit9 = digit9 % 1000000;
    int digit10 = number / 1000000;
    digit10 = digit10 % 100000;


    System.out.println("Phone number = " + number);
    System.out.println("Area code = " + digit1 + digit2 + digit3);
    System.out.println("Middle digits = " + digit4 + digit5 + digit6);
    System.out.println("Last four digits = " + digit7 + digit8 + digit9);       

}
}
```